# Make my button work when using bootstrap switch?

Tags: html, jquery-ui, bootstrap-4

I have the switch button showing on/off, when switch in between. I don't seem to see any errors on browser while inspecting it. Yet if I use JsFiddlenet as a browser IDE, the button are working fine. Maybe let me share the order of my HTML for using bootstrap and javascript.

The html Part:

```
<link href="https://raw.githack.com/jamiebicknell/Toggle-Switch/master/toggleswitch.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<pre lang="Javascript">
    <div class = "wrapper" align = "center">
       <div class="btn-group" id="toggle_event_editing">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info locked_active">OFF</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default unlocked_inactive">ON</button>
      </div> 
      <div class="alert alert-info" id="switch_status">
         Switched off. 
      </div>
  </div>
```

And the JS Part:

```
<script src ="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://raw.githack.com/jamiebicknell/Toggle-Switch/master/jquery.toggleswitch.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

   $('#toggle_event_editing button').click(function(){
    if( $(this).hasClass('locked_active') ||
        $(this).hasClass('unlocked_inactive')) {

        /* code to do when unlocking */
        $('#switch_status').html('Switched on.');
    } else {
        /* code to do when locking */
        $('#switch_status').html('Switched off.');
    }

    /* reverse locking status */
    $('#toggle_event_editing button').eq(0).toggleClass('locked_inactive locked_active btn-default btn-info');
    $('#toggle_event_editing button').eq(1).toggleClass('unlocked_inactive unlocked_active btn-info btn-default');
});
</script>
```

Comment: what do you want to implement??

Comment: Why the `pre` Tag?

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
    <body>
        <link href="https://raw.githack.com/jamiebicknell/Toggle-Switch/master/toggleswitch.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <pre lang="Javascript"><div class = "wrapper" align = "center">
          <div class="btn-group" id="toggle_event_editing">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info locked_active">OFF</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-default unlocked_inactive">ON</button>

        </div> 
        <div class="alert alert-info" id="switch_status">Switched off.</div>
         </div>

        <script src ="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='https://raw.githack.com/jamiebicknell/Toggle-Switch/master/jquery.toggleswitch.js'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

           $('#toggle_event_editing button').click(function(){
            if($(this).hasClass('locked_active') || $(this).hasClass('unlocked_inactive')){
                /* code to do when unlocking */
                $('#switch_status').html('Switched on.');
            }else{
                /* code to do when locking */
                $('#switch_status').html('Switched off.');
            }

            /* reverse locking status */
            $('#toggle_event_editing button').eq(0).toggleClass('locked_inactive locked_active btn-default btn-info');
            $('#toggle_event_editing button').eq(1).toggleClass('unlocked_inactive unlocked_active btn-info btn-default');
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: can you tell the community in two lines, what the problem was?

Comment: @helle In browser the buttons were separated in different lines!!!

Comment: @my switch button on my side does not work, the code i provided is working when i use Jfiddle.net. But why on my side i am unable to get it working?

Comment: @user12443509 you must have forgotten to include the `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @user124443509 i do have all of those, but i dont know why they dont respond back my button, Jfiddle same code i have its working there and no errors when inspecting. Still no luck

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {}); was missing and one of the reason why it did not worked before, anyway thanks mates for assisting me to troubleshoot this fast.